# c++ Xlib don't want to resize my window in height

Tags: c++, xlib

I want to resize a window with Xlib so I made a function (she is inside a class) :

```
int setSizeAndMove(int top, int left, int width, int height)
{
    XMoveResizeWindow(m_display, m_window_terminal, top, left, width, height);
    return 1;
}
```

This function works fine. I have another function who return the size of the current window :

```
Rect getWindowSize() const
{
    XWindowAttributes size_win;
        XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, m_window_terminal, &size_win);

    Rect size_return;
        size_return.X = size_win.width;
        size_return.Y = size_win.height;
    return size_return;
}
```

(Rect is just a structur that contain int X & int Y)
My problem is when I do something like this :

```
setSizeAndMove(0, 0, getWindowSize().X + 10, getWindowSize().Y + 10);
```

The window correctly add 10 pixel to width but not to height, why ?

//Additional question with 0,0 the window isn't in the top left but something like 5,5.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Works for me.  What's your window manager?

Comment: After more test the function work correctly but is slow, so to correct this I just resize while size isn't correct.